# logstash date filter add_field is not working

Tags: date, filter, logstash

I"m connecting to postgres and writing a few rows to elastic via logstash.
same date read/write is working fine.
After I apply a date fileter, fetch a date field and assign it to newly created field, it's not working. Below is the filter

```
filter {
    date {
        locale => "en"
        
        match => ["old_date", "YYYY-MM-dd"] 
        timezone => "Asia/Kolkata"
        add_field => { "newdate" => "2022-10-06"}
        target => "@newdate"
   }
}
```

I tried with mutate also but the new field is not getting created and there's no any error

Comment: you shouldn't need to create the field with `add_field `. And considering that the `add_field` operation in the filter is done after the date parsing, you might end up erasing the parsed value.

Comment: If [old_date] does not exist then the date filter is a no-op. If the parser returns a success status (which it will not if the field does not exist) then the [code](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-date/blob/2fadbbaea832f540e7ae556e7f2ec1bb594f2787/src/main/java/org/logstash/filters/DateFilter.java#L85) [adds the field](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-date/blob/2fadbbaea832f540e7ae556e7f2ec1bb594f2787/lib/logstash/filters/date.rb#L175).

Comment: old_date exists in postgres, which is available in elastic after writing. I would like to parse old_date and assign it to a newly created field new_date. new_date doesn't exist. The problem is this filter has no error and no effect

Comment: I tried this way,
filter {
      date {
       match => ["published_date", "YYYY-MM-dd"] 
        target => "@timestamp"
      }
}
it's not working. I'm new logstash, any help will be appreciable